# Good online resource for Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, resources

I'm reading the GoF book on design patterns and now everything is making a lot more sense.

I would like know if there are any good online resource to generic online patterns, preferably in C#, but it can be in any language.

Any tips?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92225/what-are-the-best-resources-for-design-patterns-and-their-uses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The articles on Wikipedia are great.  Here are some other resources you might find useful:

Sourcemaking : http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns

Portland Pattern Repository Wiki : http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PeopleProjectsAndPatterns

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Wikipedia as an initial reference?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dofactory.com/ gives a good overview and I would DEFINITELY suggest looking into the Design Pattern Framework for all of the GoF patterns (and more) with C# and optimized .NET examples using various technologies (MVC, ASP.NET WebForms, and WPF).

Also, I would recommend looking into Martin Fowler's work.  He doesn't particularly use  C#, but the patterns are pretty much the same.  He has several great books, including Patterns of Enterprise Architecture and Analysis Patterns.  He makes a lot of this available for free on his website.  http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/.